# Explicitness vs. DRY - which way is more pythonic?

Tags: python, coding-style, dry

I need the wast dictionary, maps mostly on typical values, as well as some unique ones.
1st way to obtain it is defining one flat "explicit" dictionary literal:

```
musicians = {
    'ABBA': 'pop',
    'Avril Lavigne': 'pop',
    ...
    'Mikhail Krug': 'russian chanson',
    'The Rolling Stones': 'rock',
    ...
    'Zaz': 'jazz',
}
```

2nd - "DRY" bunch of typical lists and the dictionary of specials:

```
pop_musicians = [
    'ABBA',
    'Avril Lavigne',
    ...
]

rock_musicians = [...]

unusual_musicians = {
    'Mikhail Krug': 'russian chanson',
    'Zaz': 'jazz',
}

musicians = dict(
    [(m, 'pop') for m in pop_musicians] +
    [(m, 'rock') for m in rock_musicians] +
    unusual_musicians.items()
)
```

Suppose also key-value relations much more variable (values of certain keys are likely to change) in my case than in this example.

Which way would you prefer and why? In your opinion, which one is more pythonic?

Comment: I prefer the first. It is better readable and as far as I can tell a lot shorter than your second approach. Also keep in mind that this type of question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It is more a question of taste or opinion.

Comment: I lol'd at "Mikhail Krug". Sorry.

Comment: DRY does not necessarily mean "as brief and compressed as possible".

Comment: @chepner Agreed. I think **clarity** is the important thing to value.

Comment: The second solution (or Lattyware's alternate version) has a huge advantage: if you have to type 'pop' 1000 times, you're going to get it wrong at least once… But, as Paul Manta says, if you've only got 20 of them, the first one is simpler to read.

Answer (score 9):

My answer would be to layer your data structures:

```
genres = {
    "rock": [
        "some rock band",
        "some other rock band",
    ],
    "pop": [
        "some pop star",
        "some pop group",
    ],
}
```

And if you have to have it in the first format, a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp) will do the job nicely:

```
musicians = {musician: genre for genre, musicians in genres.items() for musician in musicians}
```

Will produce:

```
{'some other rock band': 'rock', 'some pop group': 'pop', 'some rock band': 'rock', 'some pop star': 'pop'}
```

Or, if you find yourself having to do a lot of complex manipulation, maybe make a musician class to give yourself more freedom.

Comment: I also need as fast as possible retrieving value by the key. Flat dictionary is mandatory.

Comment: @leventov If you absolutely have to have that data structure (premature optimisation is a bad idea, remember), then a dictionary comprehension will do the job to convert it - see my updated answer.

Comment: +1, because this is an improvement over the OP's "DRY" solution (it's more general, and it's clearer how the structure fits together, and it still retains the benefit of not having to type "pop" 1000 times and hope you never typo). But it's probably more important to note that you've chosen his "DRY" solution over his "explicit", and why, before improving on it…

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't much sense to hash on values (they are functions) in my case. But I like your way of thinking.

Comment: @leventov Functions are objects like any other in Python, and are hashable - no reason not to use then as keys.

Answer (score 2):

For a short list of musicians, the first option would probably be best. In case you have lists that are fairly large, I'd take the second option. There's nothing unclear about it, it reduces the risk of typos (which are very likely if the dict gets big), and it also organizes musicians into visually distinct lists.